# I want to get info of each payments of a subscription in authorized.net Arb api

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I have been able to create a subscription , update subscription upto a lebel , delete / cacel a subscription and get status of a subscription !

But I want to verify if customer has been charged every month for this subscription .For that all payments details under that subscription .Is there anyway to do that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/). This is Authorize.Net's version of Paypal's IPN.

(*I am the author of that article*)